# Remove duplicated results from table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

I had a problem with my linq query.

my query goes like this:

```
var results = db.rms_section_vw.Where(s => s.sect_activeflag == true && 
                                           s.dept_isactive == true)
                               .GroupBy(s => s.sect_id)
                               .Select(r => r.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

but still in displaying the records, there are duplicates.

My table in view:

```
Dept ID     Sect ID    Dept name  Sect Name   dept_isactive   sect_isactive
      1           1       Dept 1     Sect 1               1               1
      1           2       Dept 1     Sect 2               1               1
```

When the results will be displayed:

```
Dept name          Sect name
   Dept 1             Sect 1
   Dept 1             Sect 1 (supposed to be Sect 2)
   Dept 2             Sect  3
   Dept 2             Sect  3 (supposed to be Sect 4)
```

What's wrong in  my query?

Comment: The result you getting is correct because you used GroupBy of **"SectId"** {1, 2} if the "SectId" is same then you will get the expected result.

Comment: @Chandru, I forgot, I updated my question already specifically the results displayed. The results are like that when I tried to use the query.

Comment: can you plz add some more records in table view and add expected output, because it's not more clear.

Comment: @Chandru, see edited question

Comment: According to you table you have {SectId : **1** , DeptName : Dept1, SectName : **Sect1** } and {SectId : **2** , DeptName : Dept1, SectName : **Sect2** }, if you tried with this data you will get this {"Dept1" , "Sect 1"} and {"Dept1",**"Sect2"**} but according to you output {"Dept1" , "Sect 1"} and {"Dept1",**"Sect1"**} so it's not duplicate , it means data repeating ? Am I right or your output data is wrong?

Comment: It can be repeating, yes you're right but I think it would also be duplicating since the same data is being generated.

Comment: Can you plz add some more sample records in your "My Table View" and also mention the logic thatyou are trying to achieve?

Comment: The "My table in view" is the one generated when I combined tables in the sql server. That's the result when I joined the Dept and Sect table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89247/discussion-between-chandru-and-user4656677).

Comment: Remove the firstordefault function and then try. Because each loop inside this query it will get two set of data according to the groupBy result like { sect 1, Dept 1, Sect1} and { Sect 2, Dept 1, Sect2} now you are taking the first or default value so every time you will get first data that is  { sect 1, Dept 1, Sect1}

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = db.rms_section_vw.Where(s => s.sect_activeflag == true && s.dept_isactive == true).GroupBy(s => s.sect_id).Select(r => r.FirstOrDefault()).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Still the same results.